# converting SWF to Text

Tags: text, flash

I'm hoping someone can help me out with a problem.  I have a few thousand flash files that are all text (resumes).  I need to be able to either convert the swf to text or copy all the text out of each swf file and paste it into a text file.  anyone have any ideas?

thanks
jason

Comment: I assume you have googled this? There are plenty of apps that can do this, manually or in batches.